# Is MarkLogic backup only Amazon S3 compatible?

Tags: marklogic

I have an Object Store other than Amazon's but it is S3 compatible. Is it true that MarkLogic can only be configured with Amazon's S3 and not any other S3 compatible Object Storage service ?
Upon configuring my MarkLogic instance and scheduling a backup with specifying journal archive to a local directory (not s3 URL), I still can't push backup to my Object store. This is the error that I'm receiving -

> S3 socket error: GET - XDMP-AWSSVCREG: Cannot determine AWS service and region from domain 'abc-marklogic.s3api-ddd.zyz.com'

Upon checking what `XDMP-AWSSVCREG` means, the manual says -

> Cause
>   The domain name used to access an AWS service does not look like an AWS domain name, of the form service.amazonaws.com or service.region.amazonaws.com.

Clearly my domain name is different.

Comment: I am guessing it is not officially tested against non-Amazon S3, and maybe not even tried at all. Consider reaching out to Support, if you are entitled, to file a Request For Enhancement..

Answer (score 1):

It *MIGHT POSSIBLY* work if you run a local DNS server so that you can create URI's that 'look like' AWS URIs.  I doubt it will though, "S3 Compatible" and "Actually works exactly like S3" are very different.  The next hurdle will be if your object store supports SIGV4 signatures and has a matching SSL certificate.

Recommend submitting a feature request.